# How to let boost.build's action like "make -j"?

Tags: boost, makefile, boost-build

I'm using boost.build on a 24-CPUS machine, I want it build something fast, like `make -j`, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-j` option of the `bjam` executable file defines how many CPUs will be used for boost compilation. An example

```
bjam.exe -j4 toolset=msvc-10.0 stage
```